# How to get Netflix video and sound out to TV using Ubuntu

Tags: sound, video, tv

I was trying to watch a movie on Netflix using Ubuntu OS.  I connected my computer to my TV using a VGA cable for the video and a 3.5 mm cable connected to the headphones jack for the audio.  The TV only shows my Ubuntu desktop, nothing that I do on the computer will show up on my TV.  Please help!

Comment: I wonder what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the display settings and select "mirror display"

Comment: This way, it will display the same on both screens. Resolution has to be the same aswell.